# Confused whether using the correct database design concept will make it difficult to design PHP login system

Tags: sql, database-design

I would very much appreciate any information regarding this. I have got a database that follows the correct principles, I say this because I used approached it using ERD and Normalisation to data model the database.

I am using this database for a web program that I am developing which has got a Login system. I am aware about the login system that can be implemented using the one table e.g. user table and having an extra field to define the authorisation level of the user within the system which will be so much easier to develop. But on the other hand I am confused as an compsci student to whether doing this will degrade my marks since it isn't the correct principle.

Just to clarify the database I've designed have got 3 different users and have relationship to different entities.

Thank you so much for your time and reading this !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have three different types of users, and you want to impress your teacher by not merely using one table.

A good schema would be:

`users`

for all the things they have in common

`common_data` , `admin_data`, and `organizer_data`

The former for regular login/authentication -

username
hash (password) 
access_level (or type)

-- and you might even include:

`last_login`

Or you know, whatever.

and in the other tables, have the generalized information 
(that you would be reading less-often)

```
email
phone_number
address
```

etc --

For the organizer_table, you might have groupID, which of course, you could also put in the user table -- admin_table would get something like failed_login_attempts -- or in some of my projects, I have "last_ip_address" for the admin -

But you get the idea --- separate user-entities, that require separate data-sets -- since this project doesn't seem to be very code-oriented, I'm sure you could get away with making up whatever columns that seem remotely logical

And of course, both tables get an `id` column - which provides their relationship !

Now, insofar as one table making it easier than two - you should look into `JOIN`'s - which make two tables appear as one *when you need them to* - otherwise, they can be separate entities--

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback. I understand your concept for storing relevant information into different tables but in my case I also have 3 different user who will have different access with the web page essentially it will be a system for e.g. organiser , admin , participants.

Comment: Well, then there you go - type - for the three different roles they play, and then separate tables for each --- I'll elaborate, momentarily.